# Game with insect hybrids, path selection, and points

Tags: android, game

I am looking for a game in which the character that draws all of the player's attention is a hybrid between a fly (wings and legs) and a green constructive munching bug.

In the game, the insect in question, traces out paths (which appear, as, dashed curved lines).

The, antagonists, are moth dragonflies.

The protagonist must trace paths, and gather wood, for interested persons in homes in the shape of holes in the ground.

Points are retrieved, in the amount of wood and number of people fed criteria (the instincts in the holes are able to use wood for both warmth and food).

Thus, there is a two point system that uses a function that takes into account wood gathered, wood distributed (try and put at least some wood in all holes. Insects may draw underground paths and reach a new home, leading to more points or less points if it leads to starvation due to too many insects in one hole, but, they may gather points back as they make it back to another home with more wood).

Now, the gist, of what else, is crucial, to make this game original.

You do not control the fly/green insect hybrid.

Instead, done four to six paths are displayed in the lower right area of the screen.

You select the path the insect is too take (to connect wood, and drop it into the holes. If too much wood is collected, some, drops (along, the, pathway).

There is no death. The north dragonflies are relatively static, and must be avoided in the path taking. (This happens

This is a points based game.

You must select the paths that name you make more points.

Your name can be displayed into the high scores table, at, the end of the game, along with the points versus time function graph (and, you may click on it, to his key, paths/strategy/game keepints, you might want to review and learn.

You can play the game as many times as you would like to win.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a game that you have seen before, and are asking us to find? Or, are you asking us to code it for you?